# How to shift a tikzmark?

Tags: tikzmark

I'd like the tikzmark to be centered on the line of the tabular, the optional argument seems not working or I missuse it :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}\noalign{\tikzmark[yshift=-5pt]{Z0}}\hline
foo
\end{tabular}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[orange] (pic cs:Z0) circle (.5pt) ;

\begin{tabular}{|c|}\noalign{\tikzmark[yshift=-5pt]{Z1}}
foo
\end{tabular}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[orange] (pic cs:Z1) circle (.5pt) ;

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the same reason why `\begin{tikzpicture}[yshift=-5pt]` wouldn't move a `tikzpicture` down. The option is applied to the content of the `tikzpicture` in the coordinate system of the diagram, but it doesn't affect the position of the `tikzpicture` on the baseline/page.

On the other hand, `foo\raisebox{5pt}{\tikzmark{Z0}}\tikzmark{Z1}bar \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[orange] (pic cs:Z0) -- (pic cs:Z1);` works, because the `\raisebox` moves the `tikzmark` itself on the page, like it would the letter `x` for example.

Putting a `\raisebox` in the `\noalign` didn't work, but a slightly roundabout way could be to do this:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}\noalign{\tikzmark{top}}\hline
\raisebox{5pt}{\tikzmark{baseline}}foo
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % if you want to use the same coordinate multiple times
    % it makes sense to define a named \coordinate
    \coordinate (foo) at ({pic cs:top} |- {pic cs:baseline});

    \fill[orange] (foo) circle[radius=.5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

% foo can of course be used in other tikzpictures as well
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw [->] (foo) -- ++(1cm,1cm);

\end{document}
```